# unable to export the artifactory sytem backup using rest-api

Tags: rest, artifactory

Team,

I am getting below error when i am trying to export the artifactory system.

[root@akkji01-E5154 backup]# curl -u username:password -H "content-type: application/json" -X POST "http://akkji01-e5154:8081/artifactory/api/export/system" -T {export-settings.json}
Beginning full system export...
Creating temp export directory: /artifactory/backup/20171114.131207.tmp

500 : Failed to create backup dir: /artifactory/backup/20171114.131207.tmp

Any idea?

Regards,
Jithendar

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the permissions on /artifactory and /artifactory/backup? They need to be the same owner as the artifactory service is running under. For an RPM installation that’s the userid “artifactory”.